# Laravel Nova how to query database for specific column of table

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-nova

I'm building an `laravel-nova` application and I want to query the database for a specific column in a table. The results of thsi query should be displayed as options in `select`.

```
Select::make('URLs')->options([
   // results from query here
   // maybe something like: $this->selectOptions()
])

public function selectOptions() {

  // this would be the SQL query: SELECT myfield from Mytable; 
}
```

Can someone help me out?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Laravel options of select not rendering correct values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55632933/php-laravel-options-of-select-not-rendering-correct-values)