# PHP Laravel options of select not rendering correct values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-nova

I want to display an array of values as options inside a select using the laravel-nova syntax. I managed to get the options rendered inside the select but the values of these options are like

```
<option value="2"></option>
<option value="1"></option>
<option value="0"></option>
```

what I want is the text as an value.

this is what I got so far:

```
Select::make('Slug')->options(
   $this->selectOptions()
)


public function selectOptions()
{
    $urls = DB::table('subpages');
    $slugs = $urls->pluck('slug');

    return $slugs;
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Do you want the slug in both the value and display text e.g. `<option value="my-article">my-article</option>`?

Comment: You can try `$urls->keyBy('id')->pluck('slug')`. Replace `id` with the primary key of the `subpages` table.

Comment: @Remul yes exactly! Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure to `get()` the subpages as `Illuminate\Support\Collection` and `mapWithKeys()` to reformat the results.  Use `toArray()` to provide the format Nova assumes:

```
private function selectOptions(): array
{
    $subpages = DB::table('subpages')->get();
    return $subpages->mapWithKeys(function ($subpage) {
        return [$subpage->slug => $subpage->slug];
    })->toArray();
}
```

This is how the returned result should look like:

```
[
    'my-article-1' => 'my-article-1',
    'my-article-2' => 'my-article-2',
    'my-article-3' => 'my-article-3',
]
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the following parameters:

```
->pluck('yourValue','yourKey');
```

That makes for useful labels with your values.